# How does the .init section work when booting kernel

Tags: operating-system

I am attempting to understand the boot process of a simple kernel.  Below is a linker script where I create an .init.data section.

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 1M;
    .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text)
    }

    .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }
    .init.data : {
        __initcall6_start = .;
        *(.initcall6.init)
    }
}
```

I then create `myFunc` in my simple kernel.c file.  I then create an function pointer `__initcall_myFunc6` and place it in the `.initcall6.init` section.  I assign it a reference to myFunc.

```
#include "multiboot.h"

typedef int (*initcall_t)(void);
#define __section(S) __attribute__((__section__(#S)))
#define __used __attribute__((__used__))
#define __init __section(.init.text)

static int __init myFunc(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        ;
    return 0;
}

void kernel_main(multiboot_info_t *mbd, unsigned int magic)
{
    magic = magic;
    mbd = mbd;

    while (1)
        ;
}

static __used initcall_t __initcall_myFunc6 __section(".initcall6.init") = myFunc;
```

When I load my kernel using qemu, myFunc is called prior to my kernel main.  I would expect nothing to occur, because there is nothing calling myFunc.  I have borrowed someof this from linux as I was attempting to understand the initialization of drivers.

The project can be obtained in github: https://github.com/wbranson/testOS

There is a lot of information regarding the .init and .fini sections of an ELF file, but all assume the process/program will be loaded by a kernel. I am trying to find information that explains why/how this may be occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide your kernel should have an `.init.data` section, then you also decide how your kernel should use its `.init.data` section.

For a random guess; I'd assume that you decided your kernel should have an `.init.data` section to make it easier for your kernel to discard stuff that won't be used again after initialization (so it can free the RAM and use that RAM for more useful things).

I decided my kernel should not have an `.init.data` section. This is mostly because it's a micro-kernel (there's very little kernel initialization to begin with), and because most of that initialization was shifted out of the kernel (into earlier boot code that's discarded after boot).

> When I load my kernel using qemu, myFunc is called prior to my kernel main. I would expect nothing to occur, because there is nothing calling myFunc. I have borrowed someof this from linux as I was attempting to understand the initialization of drivers.

You told the linker to use the symbol `_start` as the entry point; then you wrote code for `_start` that does `call _init`. The `_init` code is not a full function. It's the start of a function without the end (without a `return`), which causes whatever random trash the linker felt like putting after it to be executed. In your case, the "random trash the linker felt like putting after it" is your `myFunc()` (because it happened to be in the same section).

**Note that this is all hideous GCC hackery that should not exist in a kernel at all.**

More specifically, the `.init` and `.fini` mess is intended for hosted environments where you have a huge bloated run-time to worry about; and should not be used for freestanding environments like kernels where a huge bloated run-time (that depends on a kernel API that doesn't exist) can't make any sense.

Comment: Thank makes perfect sense. It was the lack of a return in the _init function that caused the confusion, thanks!